# Why can't I extract a spring boot executable jar?

Tags: jar, spring-boot

spring boot project, build as a executable jar, but I found cannot extract the executable jar, e.g.

```
jar xvf spring-boot-foo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

nothing output.
But when extract a normal jar, it is successful

```
jar xvf mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar
created: META-INF/
inflated: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
created: META-INF/services/
...
```

why is this?

Comment: Well open up the spring boot jar in your favorite zip tool. Can you? Is there anything in it?

Comment: Yeah, `unzip` could extract it. but `unizp` could extract all jar file, not only spring boot executable jar.

Comment: Winzip won't co-operate. Gives me `Error: central directory not found.`

Comment: @zhuguowei What happens when you `unzip boot.jar` that you don't like?

Answer (score 39):

You can `less` your jar file and will find the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#    .   ____          _            __ _ _
#   /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
#  ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
#   \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
#    '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
#   =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
#   :: Spring Boot Startup Script ::
#
```

That is, it's a bash file follow a jar, not a normal jar.

you can extract this file use : `unzip spring-boot-foo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

or set the executable flag of spring-boot-maven-plugin to false to make a normal jar file.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <executable>false</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: how do they do that? What can I search for to learn more about this?

Comment: It's a minor issue for me that you can't give Stack Overflow half-votes. You only answered half the question. And since you have only got 1 point rep, I'm not going to down-vote you and take it away, the karma would get me. It would ruin my peace 0ph mind.

Comment: I had to open the JAR in VI and delete the shell script at the top leaving everything after the exit command. Then `unzip spring-boot-foo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` worked.

Comment: Change executable tag to false worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 17):

I normally use 7zip to extract files on windows and it didn't work as well. Thanks to @peace0phmind I tried to open it with my Text editor (notepad++) and I saw that the content is a shell script followed by binary code.

I just removed all bash script lines, saved the file and now I can open it with 7zip.

Answer (score 15):

When using 7zip to open a Springboot executable jar you need to right-click on the .jar file and select the second 7zip option "Open Archive..." and select zip as format from the additional formats.
Selecting "Open as archive"  won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Spring boot 2.6.7 and create a executable jar using gradle bootJar task.
Now you can extract the jar eventhough it is executable.

Not sure if this is a bug in Spring boot 2.6.x

I tried with Spring boot version 2.6.7, Spring cloud version 2021.0.0, gradle 6.9.0

I am unable to restrict the jar from extracting it using any standard zip archive tools.

Answer (score 0):

`unzip` will work because it is not a `.tar` archive file.